# Why exec 'some code' in some_dict will produce a huge dictionary?

Tags: python, exec

I've see a code piece on python cook book today.

```
d={}
exec defining_code in d
```

I tried it on my terminal, and the result it returns shocked me:

```
d={1:2} 
exec 'print 1' in d
print d
{'__builtins__': {'bytearray': <type 'bytearray'>, 
# Here I omitted hundreds of key-value pairs},
1:2}
```

Is this some trick like 'import this'? If it is, why the designer make it in such form? If it's not a trick, what's the mechanism under it?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement) on the exec statement:

> As a side effect, an implementation may insert additional keys into the dictionaries given besides those corresponding to variable names set by the executed code. For example, the current implementation may add a reference to the dictionary of the built-in module **builtin** under the key **builtins** (!).

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still confused